# How to sync folders between iPad and Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, data-synchronization, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPad and a Macbook Pro running OS X Yosemite with PPSSPP (PSP emulator) installed on both. What I need is to make folder with saves automatically sync every now and then. My first thought was BitTorrent Sync, but it seems it can't sync system folders. Is there any way to do this or I'm stuck with playing only on one device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install FTP on the device, and set up a AppleScript that copies the data from your iOS device every 15 minutes. Then, you could set up a folder action, and whenever your Mac's folder is modified, it copies the contents of that folder to your iOS device.

(*Note: I can't give you any example scripts since I'm not on my Mac right now.*)

Comment: Well, that seems to be a solution and I'll try it, but I was looking for something more straightforward like the aforementioned BTSync. Thank you anyway, I wouldn't have thought of FTP